# How to copy a string using for loop

Tags: java, android, performance, textview

I have a string question in which a string is stored example.

I have to copy the string into another string (not all thing).

For that i want to use for loop while traversing the string so that i can decide whether to copy it or not .

I write the code here i did not give any condition .I just simply traverse the string and copy it but it give me error.

```
String question;
String[] questioncopy;
String[] arrquestion;
String[] arrquestion=question.split("");

for(i=0;i<arrquestion.length;i++){
    questioncopy[i]=arrquestion[i];         
}

String asString = Arrays.toString(questioncopy);
```

why it give error or suggest some more idea

NOTE:I want copy the string in string variable not in string[];

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: You never initialize your Strings... They're all `null`

Comment: One issue I see is that `arrquestion` is declared twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to copy into an other array.

```
String[] arrquestion=question.split("");
String asString="";
for(i=0;i<arrquestion.length;i++){
    asString +=arrquestion[i];
}
```

Also you can't declare twice a variable (arrquestion here) and when you want to use an array, you need to declare it before.

```
String[] questioncopy = new String[];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You haven't initialize the question string. So question.split will throw nullpointer exception and arrquestion.length will be same
2. YOu have declared arrquestion twice. So will show compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign into String[] questionCopy.
For what you're trying to do, questionCopy should be a char[] (or CharArray), assign into the values, set the length, and then convert that to a String (new String(questionCopy)).

Comment: Well, you can assign into questionCopy, because it's an array, not a String. But since it's an uninitialized array, assigning into it is a Really Bad Idea.

Also, I think it's usually better to use StringBuilder than char[] or CharArray.

Comment: I suggested a char array as a minimal change to what's there. But, yes, appending to a StringBuilder is an even better idea.